# Gson to json add map dynamically to object

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, gson

I have an object that represents an event that I would like to serialize into json, using gson or another library if that works easier.

I want to add the following type of field to the json:

```
private Map<String, String> additionalProperties;
```

And also in another use case:

```
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties;
```

But if I add additionalProperties to the Event object, and build Gson in the normal way:

```
Gson gson = BUILDER.create();
String json = gson.toJson(event);
```

It will appear like so:

```
additional_properties: {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
```

I would simply like to append to the event object in the following form:

```
{"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
```

Here is an example output- the additional properties added are the object 'z' and the object 'advertiser':

```
{"organisationid":"2345612ß","projectid":"12345678",
"place":{"placeId":"2345","last_place":"123-3"},
"advertiser":{"advertiserId":"2345a","code":"a123-3"},
"user":{"isY":false,"isHere":false,"isBuyer":false},
"x":{"identifier":"SHDG-28CHD"},
"z":{"identifier":"abcSHDG-28CHD"},
"event_type":"x_depart"}
```

Here is what it currently looks like:

```
{"organisationid":"2345612ß","projectid":"12345678",
"place":{"placeId":"2345","last_place":"123-3"},
additionalproperty: {"advertiser":{"advertiserId":"2345a","code":"a123-3"},
"user":{"isY":false,"isHere":false,"isBuyer":false},
"x":{"identifier":"SHDG-28CHD"},
additionalproperty: {"z":{"identifier":"abcSHDG-28CHD"}},
"event_type":"x_depart"}
```

Comment: to clarify your problem, you've shared a json text (with editing your post). But I don't understand that what should it show us. To be more clear, can you share 2 jsons, which one shows us what you have, and another one what you want.

Comment: OK no problem - done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve this would be with a framework for adding properties dynamically, but without this, you could add the additional properties to your Event object (include @JsonIgnore
so that it is not part of the final json), create a new JSONObject from the additional properties and merge it to the event JSONObject before serializing to json. This way the additional properties are added dynamically to the resulting Event output.

## In the Event class:

```
@JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties;

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperties(Map<String, Object> additionalProperties) {
        this.additionalProperties = additionalProperties;
    }
```

## A function to merge two JSONObjects:

```
public static JSONObject mergeObjects(JSONObject source, JSONObject target) throws JSONException {
    for (String key: JSONObject.getNames(source)) {
            Object value = source.get(key);
            if (!target.has(key)) {
                // new value for "key":
                target.put(key, value);
            } else {
                // existing value for "key" - recursively deep merge:
                if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject valueJson = (JSONObject)value;
                    deepMerge(valueJson, target.getJSONObject(key));
                } else {
                    target.put(key, value);
                }
            }
    }
    return target;
}
```

## Putting the two objects together:

```
 String jsonAdd = mapper.writeValueAsString(additional);
 String jsonEvent = mapper.writeValueAsString(event);

 JSONObject jsonAddObj = new JSONObject(jsonAdd);
 JSONObject JsonEventObj = new JSONObject(jsonEvent);
 JSONObject finalJson = Merge.deepMerge(jsonAddObj, JsonEventObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Event` class is something like;

```
class Event {
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties;
}
```

and you are calling;

```
String json = gson.toJson(event);
```

The ecpected and the valid output would be:

```
{"additionalProperties":{"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}}
```

If you want an output such as;

```
{"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
```

You can call;

```
String json = gson.toJson(event.additionalProperties);
```

> I would simply like to append to the event object in the following
>   form:
>
> ```
> {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
> ```

That way it won't be a valid json variable if you append that value directly to a json object. You should better try if the json value you want is valid or not at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: Thanks for the answer- this is something i already considered but i have other variables that i want to serialize to json within the Event object as well and toJson does not accept two args of objects